# Alternative .execCommand('insertText') for Opera

Tags: javascript, insert, opera, execcommand

Seems like in **Opera**, can't use command `InsertText`

```
document.queryCommandEnabled('insertText'); // false
```

but

```
document.queryCommandEnabled('insertHTML'); // true
```

How can i get this work in Opera ?

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'test');
```

Comment: Inserting text with `insertHTML` doesn't work in Opera?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.opera` for checking Opera, but which commands are supported, as well as their behavior varies across browsers. Firefox commands you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands). For IE [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).